# Spring Data Pageable: Returns empty content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm new with Spring Data and Spring MVC and I don't understand why am I getting empty content:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pages", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody 
public Page<Client> contactsPages(@RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort("id"));
    Page<Client> pageResult = clientRepository.findAll(pageable);

    return pageResult;
}
```

The result of my json when I test the url is:

```
{"content":[],"last":true,"totalElements":2,"totalPages":1,"size":5,"number":1,"sort":[{"direction":"ASC","property":"id","ignoreCase":false,"nullHandling":"NATIVE","ascending":true}],"first":false,"numberOfElements":0}
```

And if you have good example making pageable request using Spring Data and Spring MVC and AngularJS; It will be a big help for me.

Comment: What page number are you requesting?

Comment: I requested page =1 BUT now it's working fine I tested with page=0!

Comment: The first one should be 0 indeed

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You're a life savior

Answer (score 82):

Ensure that your `PageRequest` object is requesting `0` for small sets, not `1`.

The pagination begins from `0`.

This is a common mistake for beginners and is a common redherring when using `@Query` in conjunction with Spring pagination. If your `@Query` works without pagination and then returns nothing when using it, check the page number.

Comment: what do you mean requesting for 0 for small sets?

Comment: Omg, whole night I tried to solve this problem. Page index 0 :(

Comment: @Tugrul I spend the last 4 hours trying resolve this issue and all it was that I was passing PageNumber as 1 instead of 0.

Comment: 2 hours to resolve this issue, thanks man

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been just struggling to debug around my 
ugly code.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and with mine it was due to the fact that I modify the data after doing a select such that the modified field is the same field I use for searching. This means each time I run the query it will match less and less records so page zero will always have new data, so in that instance using page 0 always will not hurt as new records will always fill page zero. In the other instance I did not modify the search field and my query will match the same records each time I execute my select statement so in this instance requesting the exact page was important.

Comment: you are genius. spent 4 hours on this. First I was using a flag to select records and after that if everything was good I was updating the flag and in this way removing the records from my next page. Could not understand why is so linear, always removing me 1/2 of the records

Answer (score -2):

Dharman's answer helps me find out the reason.
If you use pagination to get data from DB, and also you update the search field after you retrieve it, then the page info will get messed up.